# Going through string columns and sort cell values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1':['cat; banana','kiwi; orange; apple','melon'],
    'col2':['a; d; c','p; u; c','m; a'],
    'col3':[4,1,4]}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

for all the string columns I want to sort the values alphabetically, I know how to do this column by column, namely:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: '; '.join(sorted(x.split('; '))))
```

and similarly for `col2` I wonder how one can does this for the whole dataframe? I tried to select the string objects and do the map method, but it didn't work. Namely:

```
df.select_dtypes(include='object').map(lambda x: '; '.join(sorted(x.split('; '))))
```

**Update:** So an inefficient way of doing this would be:

```
v = df.select_dtypes(include='object').applymap(lambda x: '; '.join(sorted(x.split('; '))))
w = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
pd.concat([v, w], axis=1)
```

But I am sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this trick (unpacking a dataframe and using `pd.DataFrame.assign`):

```
df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(include='object').applymap(lambda x: '; '.join(sorted(x.split('; ')))))
```

Output:

```
                  col1     col2  col3
0          banana; cat  a; c; d     4
1  apple; kiwi; orange  c; p; u     1
2                melon     a; m     4
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in an inefficient for loop with a test to make sure that you are not applying it to the ints

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtypes is 'str':
        df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: '; '.join(sorted(x.split('; '))))
```

there maybe a better vectorized way

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't `is` be `==`?

Comment: `==` would return False or True and as we are sorting the column it would all be False unless every line is already sorted...  I think that I have lost you on this comment.